# Apache Camel SQL component is not closing resultset?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel sql component to run select queries against Oracle DB. The war file is deployed on Jboss EAP 6.1. In the config file under  configuration I have track-statements set to true (i.e. true). So Jboss checks if the result sets are closed when a connection is returned back to the pool.

I am configuring sql component as follows:

```
//datasource is injected here
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/jdbc/OracleDS")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

...
...

```
//SQL component
SqlComponent sqlComponent = new SqlComponent();
sqlComponent.setDataSource(dataSource);
camelCtx.addComponent("sql", sqlComponent);
```

The sql component is used in a recipientList as follows:

```
from("activemq:"+queue)
...
.recipientList(simple(getFromConfig(sqlStmtName)),"false")
..
```

The sql statement is nothing special. Just a regular select statement from a single table.

In Jboss logs I see this warning.

```
2015-04-16 16:23:07,169 WARN     [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection] (ajp-8009-2|R:r2K4crKLnPRT-0br|ctvc|1.0) Closing a result set you left open! Please close it yourself.: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.registerResultSet(WrappedStatement.java:1357)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.getResultSet(WrappedStatement.java:740)
at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:127)
at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:90)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer.process(SqlProducer.java:90)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:573)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:506)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:215)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:167)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
...
...
```

---

I checked SqlProducer.java (line 127). Since sql component uses Spring JDBCtemplate I would assume that resultset would be closed by the template.

Is there anything I need to do to close the resultset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is a bug in Apache Camel. I have logged a ticket to get this fixed in future releases

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8715

Comment: Thanks Claus. I will look at using newer version of Camel.